# Problem in program to print hashtags in escalting order

Tags: c, cs50

I'm learning C by cs50 in edX for a day. Week 1 of cs50 in edX was about making several rows of sharps that the number is escalating by the row increases like this:

```
#
##
###
####
#####
```

If I answer "Height=5".

I have no idea how to do it. What can I do in this code?

Here's my code:

```
// Print escalating numbers of sharp marks
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    do
    {
        n = get_int("Height:");
    }
    while (n > 1 && n < 8);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j == n; j++)
        {
            printf("#");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `while (!(n > 1 && n < 8))`

Comment: And init n unconditionally as `int n=1;`, it probably makes debugging easier.

Comment: `for (int j = 0; j == n; j++)` is weird. Try `for (int j = 0; j <= n; j++)`.

Answer (score 1):

Your program has two basic problems:

#### 1.

The condition of the `do while` loop `n > 1 && n < 8` is wrong. With that, you iterate the loop as long as `n` is between `1` and `8`. I think you want the opposite - to only iterate if `n` is not between `1` and `8`. Use `n < 1 || n > 8` or alternatively `!(n > 1 && n < 8)` instead.

#### 2.

The inner `for` loop*s condition is wrong, too. `for (int j = 0; j == i; j++)` - With that you only print one `#` per row. You need `for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)` instead.

#### 3.

You need to print a newline after the input to correctly format the output of the `#`s.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int n;
    do
    {
        n = get_int("Height: ");
    }
    while (n < 1 || n > 8);


    putchar('\n');


    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
        {
            printf("#");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Execution:

```
./a.out
Height: 5
#
##
###
####
#####
```

[Online Test](https://godbolt.org/z/1Yhcd96)

---

Technically there is also another sneaky way to achieve when you don't want to have the extra statement to print the newline.

Here we change the outer `for` loop statement to `for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)` and inner to `for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)`.

We use one iteration inside of the outer `for` loop more and print only the newline in the first walkthrough.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int n;
    do
    {
        n = get_int("Height: ");
    }
    while (n < 1 || n > 8);


    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            printf("#");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Execution:

```
./a.out
Height: 5
#
##
###
####
#####
```

[Online Test](https://godbolt.org/z/nsbcM6)